# How to set flexible height for parent div in css

Tags: html, css

How to set flexible height for parent div. In my code popup is there inside div. If I open the popup i want to increase the height of the parent div. I have used height:100% but it is not working. So, How to resolve this issue.

HTML:

```
<div class="main"> 
    <a href="#" open-popup>Popup</a>
    <maincontent class="content"> 
                 shadow-root(open)
                 <popup class="popup"> ..content..</popup> 
    </maincontent > 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main{
height:100%;
width:100%;
display:table;
border:2px solid #ccc;
}
.content{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
}
```

Getting like this:
[image]

Expected like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto height

```
height: auto;
```

instead of

```
height:100%;
```

to not disturb height of parent div

Comment: I have tried but not working.

Comment: can you provide whole code with pop up included?

Answer (score 0):

To **main** class you can use display **"block"** property instead of **"table"** and heigth will be **"auto"** or just don't define it will take automatically take.

```
<div class="main">
<a href="#" open-popup>Popup</a>
<main class="content">
  shadow-root(open)
  <div class="popup"> ..content..</div>
</main>
```

```
.main{
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  border:2px solid #ccc;
}
.content {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```